# RGB curves in Quartz Composer

Tags: objective-c, swift, augmented-reality, photoshop, quartz-composer

I'm trying to figure out how to translate (even if roughly) RGB curves from Photoshop into Quartz Composer - and ultimately into iOS. Any ideas on the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For generating a LUT in Photoshop use **File > Export > Color Lookup Tables**.

For importing LookUp Table into Quartz Composer composition you may use **JavaScript** patch. Look at this post: [How to use LUT with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910234/how-to-use-lut-with-javascript)

Touching iOS development, you should get acquainted with Quartz Composer runtime implementation for iOS on GitHub (by Joris Kluivers). Find it here:

https://github.com/kluivers/qc-mobile